# ion-item with checkbox and "a" element - click on "a" element clicks whole item and checkbox

Tags: checkbox, click, ionic3, label

I have `ion-item`, with `ion-checkbox` and `ion-labels` elements inside, and an `a` element inside `ion-label`:

```html
<ion-item class="userAgreement" text-wrap no-border no-lines>
  <ion-checkbox formControlName="agreementCheckbox"></ion-checkbox>
  <ion-label>I accept the terms of 
     <a (click)="GoToUserAgreementPage()" class="linkText">User 
     Agreement</a>
  </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Checkbox is clickable itself, but when I click on `User agreement` text inside `ion-label`, whole `ion-item` is clicked and it affects checkbox. I want checkbox to be clickable only if clicked on itself, and be able to click only on that part of text inside `a` element `inside ion-label`.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/checkbox/Checkbox/) that's actually how a checkbox with a label wrapped in an ion-item works.

To get the behaviour you want, don't wrap your checkbox and label in an ion-item, but instead recreate the look of an ion-item. Therefore you could use `display: flex` or a grid.

Raw draft using `display: flex` and some inline styles looks something like this:

```html
<div style="align-items: center; display: flex">
    <ion-checkbox style="padding-right: 10px" formControlName="agreementCheckbox"></ion-checkbox>
        <ion-label>I accept the terms of
                <a (click)="GoToUserAgreementPage()" class="linkText">User Agreement</a>
        </ion-label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `ion-checkbox` within another `ion-item`. It appears to me the parent `ion-item` will not propagate click events to any controls inside child `ion-item`s.

Clicking on the child `ion-item` will toggle the checkbox as expected.

```html
<ion-item class="userAgreement" text-wrap no-border no-lines>

  <ion-item>

    <ion-checkbox formControlName="agreementCheckbox"></ion-checkbox>

  </ion-item>

  <ion-label>I accept the terms of 
    <a (click)="GoToUserAgreementPage()" class="linkText">User Agreement</a>
  </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the ion checkbox with an ion-item. In my case I don't want any label but if you want just use for.

```
<ion-item class="userAgreement" text-wrap no-border no-lines>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-checkbox formControlName="agreementCheckbox"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-label>I accept the terms of 
     <a (click)="GoToUserAgreementPage()" class="linkText">User 
     Agreement</a>
  </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```